# PostgreSQL-10.5 union to have single record (combine null values)

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL-10.5. I have two tables to generate a report from. I need to do some calculation using `ilkokuma` (first reading) and `sonokuma` (last reading) column.

I could do calculations up to a point. I will be adding some more. I could not see how I can `join` same table in single SQL and tried to use two use `union`. Below is my current SQL which I try to combine both calculations.

```
SELECT 
  faturadata.*, 
    (SELECT DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', ilkokuma) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)) as ilkokuma_gun_sayisi,
    sabityanma.deger as ilkokuma_deger,
    (SELECT DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', ilkokuma) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)) * sabityanma.deger as ilkokuma_carpim,
    null as sonokuma_gun_sayisi,
    null as sonokuma_deger,
    null as sonokuma_carpim 
FROM 
  faturadata
left join sabityanma on sabityanma.yil = date_part('year', ilkokuma) and sabityanma.ay = date_part('month', ilkokuma)

union

SELECT 
  faturadata.*, 
    null as ilkokuma_gun_sayisi,
    null as ilkokuma_deger,
    null as ilkokuma_carpim,
    (SELECT DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', sonokuma) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)) as sonokuma_gun_sayisi,
    sabityanma.deger as sonokuma_deger,
    (SELECT DATE_PART('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', sonokuma) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)) * sabityanma.deger as sonokuma_carpim
FROM 
  faturadata
left join sabityanma on sabityanma.yil = date_part('year', sonokuma) and sabityanma.ay = date_part('month', sonokuma)
```

And result is

```
id       tesisat     trf     kwh     tahakkuk     ilkokuma     sonokuma     ilkokuma_gun_sayisi     ilkokuma_deger     ilkokuma_carpim     sonokuma_gun_sayisi     sonokuma_deger     sonokuma_carpim
2023772  4024546     400     1765    2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31   31                      9                  279               
2023772  4024546     400     1765    2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31                                                                  31                      11                 341
2023773  4024545     400     3876    2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31   31                      9                  279               
2023773  4024545     400     3876    2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31                                                                  31                      11                 341
2023774  4024543     400     2126    2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31   31                      9                  279               
2023774  4024543     400     2126    2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31                                                                  31                      11                 341
```

As it can be seen that SQL is duplicating records. What I need to do is to have single record for both calculations.

I could not figure how I can do that.

Comment: take a look at "SELECT DISTINCT"
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/

Comment: There are no duplicate rows in the result

Comment: each pair (lines 1 and 2, lines 3 and 4) is a duplicate in result

Answer (score 0):

Please shorten your example next time a little bit :)

My I removed some columns in my test table

```
id          tahakkuk     ilkokuma     sonokuma     ilko_gun_say   ilko_deger   sono_gun_say   sono_gun_deger
2023772     2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31   31             9
2023772     2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31                               31             11
2023773     2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31   31             9
2023773     2016-08-31   2016-07-31   2016-08-31                               31             11
```

You can do a simple group to aggregate your rows:

```
SELECT
    id, tahakkuk, ilkokuma, sonokuma,
    MAX(ilko_gun_say) as ilko_gun_say,
    MAX(ilko_deger) as ilko_deger,
    MAX(sono_gun_say) as sono_gun_say,
    MAX(sono_gun_deger) as sono_gun_deger
FROM 
    <YOUR QUERY HERE>
GROUP BY
    id, tahakkuk, ilkokuma, sonokuma
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=458a459cf59f3e8dc68031c4a780362e)

---

I didn't thought about a general optimization of your query because I get confused by your language. But there is a lot of code repetition. I guess there's a lot to optimize - maybe with CTEs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)?